# Returning boolean instead of list

Tags: java, spring-boot, collections, orm, java-stream

1. user class with fields id, name and types

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Types> types;
}
```

2. Types class with fields id, name , linkedTo

```
{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String linkedTo;

}
```

3. Implemented a method to get types from user and return it as list

```
private List<Types> getType(List<User> Users) {
        return Users
                .stream()
                .map(User::gettypes)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }}
```

4. Now, have to map to response body. For that I have response class:

```
    public class UserResponse {

    private String id;
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private String linkedTo;

}
```

5. Have to map the fields from Types to user response to return it as list

```
private List<UserResponse> getUserResponse(UserRequest request) {
        List<User> Users = userServiceClient.getById();
        List<UserResponse> userResponses = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Types> TypesList = getType(Users);
            if (!typesList.isEmpty()) {
            return typesList.stream()
                    .map(type -> userResponses.add(new UserResponse( type.getGuid(),type.getName(),type.getName(),type.getLinkedTo())))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
   return collections.emptylist();
    }
```

Here is the problem, I'm not able to return it as list instead getting a boolean..

Is there any efficient way to do this? The code reviewer doesn't want me to use for each and return the list

Comment: You aren't returning anything from the method

Comment: @AndrewTobilko edited the question. it has to return user response

Comment: Now you aren't returning anything from the method **when `typesList.isEmpty()`**

Comment: Check out what `List::add` returns, and what `Stream::map` does. You ***are*** making a list of `Boolean`. Code overall appears like you're incorrectly converting a for-loop into stream for whatever reason: don't. Leave the loop be.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko edited the question to return the empty list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better appraoch would be

```
private List<UserResponse> getUserResponse(UserRequest request) {
    List<User> Users = userServiceClient.getById();
    List<Types> TypesList = getType(Users);
    return typesList.stream()
            .map(type -> new UserResponse(type.getId(), type.getName(), type.getName(), type.getLinkedTo()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Reason:

- If `typesList` is empty, this would return empty `List`, as `Collections.emptyList` in your code.
- It `map`s to the `UserResponse` objects and collects them to return the `List<UserResponse>` while using the Stream for it without the explicit instantiation and `.add` call.